# Cannot delete iso 9660 partition from hard drive, cannot successfully make new partition table

Tags: hard-disk, iso

I seem to have similar problem as [USB drive cannot be formatted after burning ISO image on it (ISO 9660)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/599231/usb-drive-cannot-be-formatted-after-burning-iso-image-on-it-iso-9660). But The thing of mine is not USB, it is 4Tb drive, I would be a pity to throw it away after burning ISO image to it. Can hard drives become write-protected too? I cannot delete partition, I cannot make new partition table (although Gparted reports OK on making it, where as in linked post: " I installed Gparted. Nothing, it displayed a message saying that it couldn't format the ISO9660 partition nor create a new partition table"). Gparted strangely complains that partition tables on all connected drives does not fully look GPT (no MS-DOS something).

I tried to reclaim it via Linux Mint (Gparted) and Fedora (Disks) when I start live versions and disk is connected via SATA. The disk was "burned" via Make Bootable USB in Linux Mint when it was connected via USB. I would be weird if change made via USB protocol can be undone only that way...Or not?

I have not tried other methods mentioned in posts on USB drives, how can I proceed safely now?

Added per comment:

```
$ls -ld /dev/sda*
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8 (time/date) /dev/sda
```

Also, I've tried to format with `disks` and it formatted to ext4 and I was able to write to it and it is almost 4Tb. But still cannot delete it (no such option for it, whereas there is "-" for partition on another disk)...I would like to have control over hard drive as "normal".

Added 2:
Noted parted showed partition table as `loop`. Per https://askubuntu.com/questions/381211/what-is-the-loop-partition-in-ubuntu "Also worth noting (adding "Reason Three" to @user68186's answer) is that parted shows loop as the "partition table" for disks that actually do not have a partition table (whole disk filesystem)." I solved issue with fdisk, strangely Gparted failed here.

Comment: ASSUMING the disk in question is represented as `/dev/sdb`, please add `mount | awk '$3=="/dev" || $0~/sdb/'` and `ls -ld /dev/sdb*`

Comment: @roaima, I added ls -ld, partition is not mounted now, mount | grep sda gives nothing, should I mount it or run mount | awk anyway?

Comment: Check the `dmesg` output for any references to the disk in question: there might be information on device-level read-only mode. If it says the drive "supports TCG Opal", that is a *self-encrypting drive* that may have password protection applied to configurable ranges of it. TCG Opal may also make the partition table area read-only. Such features might have been used in some way by the USB connection adapter, if it was originally part of the packaged product the disk was sold as.

Comment: Really `sda`? Ok. Please run the comments I've given you with `sda` instead of `sdb`. If you don't get a line from `mount` for `/dev` use this instead `mount | awk '$3=="/" || $0~/sda/'` but that would be unusual for normal distributions such as Mint or Fedora

Comment: @roaima, ok. it outputed one line: `devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,...)`. How can it help with my problematic sda? (disk in now in Fedora live).

Comment: @telcoM, for `dmesg | grep sda` I got `Write protect is off, mode sense: 00 3a 00 00, write/read cache enabled, does not support DPO or FUA` also strangely `[sda] attached SCISI disk`. `dmesg | grep Opal` gave empty output.

Comment: Nothing from `mount` for `sda`?

Comment: @roaima, nope. Should it if it is not mounted now?

Comment: `dd bs=1M count=1 if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda` will overwrite the beginning of the disk. Does this generate any error message? After you've done that, what does `parted /dev/sda print` tell you?

Comment: @roaima, I'm slightly afraid to make changes to disk. Could dd be reversed? Also w/out write parted wrote `partition table: loop`, whereas for another now attached SATA drive it said `gpt`. Also for problematic sda Start is 0B, whereas for sdb 1049kB.

Comment: @roaima, I want disk in "normal" condition. Does not `loop` point to anything? Still good idea to try to write?

Comment: Loop? Ok so that explains why the disk is locked. `losetup` in your question please (as root)

Comment: @roaima, thank you. Thinking about writing to disk I tried parted and new partition was gone after parted quiting. But strangely (to me, as Gparted's making gpt table resulted in nothing visible) fdisk was able to successfully make new gpt partition table and now all looks normal. I have not made any changes via losetup and now after fdisk looks nothing on sda can be found there. Could you explain why fdisk succeeded where Gparted failed? Why partition table was loop? Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to helpful comments I solved the issue. Noted `parted` showed partition table as `loop`. Per https://askubuntu.com/questions/381211/what-is-the-loop-partition-in-ubuntu "Also worth noting (adding "Reason Three" to @user68186's answer) is that parted shows loop as the "partition table" for disks that actually do not have a partition table (whole disk filesystem)."

I solved issue with fdisk, which successfully made `gpt` partition table, whereas table which I tried to make with Gparted vanished after exit from Gparted.